# Display original filename from multipart file upload

Tags: java, spring, pdf, file-upload, filenames

How can I get the original filename after uploading the pdf file as a multipart file in Spring Java?

I upload the pdf file and it will show in table row but It just shows as below,
**org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@17dbc7f5**

```
public List<UIPrmClaimTransportationRecord> addTransportClaimToList(UIPrmClaimTransportationRecord toAdd, List<UIPrmClaimTransportationRecord> toReturn) throws ParseException, CoreException, CoreKnownException, NumberFormatException {
        if (toAdd == null)
            throw new CoreException("toAdd object is null", Constants.ERROR_CODE_ER0999);
        if (toAdd.getTranscationDateInString() == null || toAdd.getTranscationDateInString().equals(Constants.EMPTY_STRING))
            throw new CoreKnownException(Constants.ERROR_CODE_ER0059, Constants.ERROR_CODE_ER0059);
        if (toAdd.getType() == null || toAdd.getType().equals(Constants.EMPTY_STRING))
            throw new CoreKnownException(Constants.ERROR_CODE_ER0031, Constants.ERROR_CODE_ER0031);
        if (toAdd.getAmountInString() == null || toAdd.getAmountInString().equals(Constants.EMPTY_STRING))
            throw new CoreKnownException(Constants.ERROR_CODE_ER0097, Constants.ERROR_CODE_ER0097);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(propertiesConstants.getSimpleDateFormat());
        sdf.parse(toAdd.getTranscationDateInString());

        Double toTest = Double.parseDouble(toAdd.getAmountInString());
        if (toTest < 1)
            throw new CoreKnownException(Constants.ERROR_CODE_ER0033, Constants.ERROR_CODE_ER0033);

        if (toReturn == null)
            toReturn = new ArrayList<UIPrmClaimTransportationRecord>();

        toAdd.getEndLocation().toUpperCase().toString();
        toAdd.getStartLocation().toUpperCase().toString();
        toAdd.getReason().toUpperCase().toString();
        toAdd.getUploadFile();

        toReturn.add(toAdd);

        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but... have you tried toAdd.getUploadFile().getOriginalFileName()?

Comment: yeah. I had tried that one.but I can't get the original file name. do I need to write another method to get file name?